# Changing font and text color of UIViewScroll with each scroll action

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a custom UIScrollView I made for a picker and I am trying to change the color and font of the selected line.

I tried following some online tutorials about how to implement this using a coordinator but nothing seems to work for me.

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I would like to have

[image]

This is all the code I wrote so far:

```
struct CustomPicker: View {
  @State var offset: CGFloat = 0

let integers: [Int]
let doubles: [String]

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            CustomSlider(sliderItems: integers.count, offset: $offset, content: {
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(integers, id: \.self ){ index in
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 90, maxHeight: 90)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            print("DEBUG: \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            //maxHeight
            .frame(maxWidth: 90 , maxHeight: 270)
            Text(",")
                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
            
            CustomSlider(sliderItems: doubles.count, offset: $offset, content: {
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(doubles, id: \.self ){ index in
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 90, maxHeight: 90)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            print("DEBUG: \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            //maxHeight
            .frame(maxWidth: 90 , maxHeight: 270)
        }
    }
}
}

func  getRect()-> CGRect {
  return UIScreen.main.bounds
}


struct CustomSlider<Content: View> : UIViewRepresentable {

var content: Content

//Binding offset for KG calculcations
@Binding var offset : CGFloat
var sliderItems: Int

init(sliderItems: Int, offset: Binding<CGFloat>,@ViewBuilder content: @escaping ()->Content){
    self.content = content()
    self._offset = offset
    self.sliderItems = sliderItems
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return CustomSlider.Coordinator(parent: self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIScrollView {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let swiftUIView = UIHostingController(rootView: content).view!
    
    //So SwiftUI height will be total of sliderItems multiplied with the frame height (90) + offset (2 * 90)
    let height =  CGFloat(sliderItems * 90) + 180
    
    swiftUIView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: height)
    
    scrollView.contentSize = swiftUIView.frame.size
    scrollView.addSubview(swiftUIView)
    //scrolling is not magnetic
    scrollView.bounces = false
    //hide scroll indicator
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return scrollView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate{
    var parent: CustomSlider
    
    init(parent: CustomSlider){
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView ){
        parent.offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        print((scrollView.contentOffset.y / 90 ).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset  = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let value = (offset / 90).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
        
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: value * 90), animated: true)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        //if end decelarate not fired
        if !decelerate {
            let offset  = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let value = (offset / 90).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
            
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: value * 90), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `ScrollView` with `GeometryReader` to identify if the offset is at the center should work. Search SO for how to identify `ScrollView` position, there are many options.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that road. ScrollView doesn't allow me to customize the appearance of the wheelType picker. This is why I am forced to use a custom picker.